# Refrigerator filter dripping

Tags: water, filter

Replaced water filter   its dripping      we are leaving and turning off water   will that stop it from dripping while away for an extended period/

Answer (score 0):

Turning the water off will limit the supply of water but it may drip unless you try and fill a glass of water (yes with the water off) this will remove the pressure from the system and should stop the dripping.

Comment: thanks.  should i just take filter out while gone?

Comment: That is up to you in the cold it would be less likely to grow bacteria, if it’s time for a change sure pull it and put a new one in when you return.

Answer (score 0):

The filter should have (2) copper compression fittings on each end. Shut the water off, remove the filter than unscrew the fitting that dripping. Wrap Teflon tape around the threads and hand tighten to the filter.

If it's the tubing side of the fitting that's dripping remove the nut to expose the compression ring. Re-seat the tube in the ring and tighten it to the fitting with the nut.

Comment: Some pros recommend always replacing the compression rings.